statement node is not selected in Treesitter playground
Here is the sample code
import {One} from 'somewhere'

const five: number = 5

Here is the generated tree
program [0, 0] - [3, 0]
  import_statement [0, 0] - [0, 29]
    import_clause [0, 7] - [0, 12]
      named_imports [0, 7] - [0, 12]
        import_specifier [0, 8] - [0, 11]
          name: identifier [0, 8] - [0, 11]
    source: string [0, 18] - [0, 29]
      string_fragment [0, 19] - [0, 28]
  lexical_declaration [2, 0] - [2, 22]
    variable_declarator [2, 6] - [2, 22]
      name: identifier [2, 6] - [2, 10]
      type: type_annotation [2, 10] - [2, 18]
        predefined_type [2, 12] - [2, 18]
      value: number [2, 21] - [2, 22]

I'm trying to query it with
(statement) @something

I expect it to highlight the import_statement and the lexical_declaration nodes because of the parser definition in tree-sitter-javascript/.../node-types.json (which is imported in typescript parser)
Unfortunately, it does not. However, when I use (declaration) @something, then it highlights the lexical_declaration node and when I use (import_statement) @something then it highlights the import_statement node.
So how do I use the supertype statement to capture both?

you could capture twice.
